# Is there a way to "and" two decision procedures into one in Coq?

Tags: coq

I am trying to define a function in Coq with a if ... then ... else ... and in my condition for 'if' I would like to test if a nat is in a interval.

For instance a, b, x are nat and I want to test if x is in the interval [a,b], so I would like to have a condition like `if (le_gt_dec a x)/\(lt_dec x b) then ... else ...` but this doesn't work because the type wanted by the '/\' is Prop on both side and le_gt_dec is not Prop.
So I get the error : `The term "le_gt_dec a x" has type "{a <= x} + {a > x}"
while it is expected to have type "Prop"`

I also tried `if (le_gt_dec a x)&&(lt_dec x b) then ... else ...` but this doesn't work neither.

The only solution I have found for now is to do an if...then...else... inside another if...then...else... so for the function IsIn that I gave as an example it would be :

```
if (le_gt_dec a x) then ( if (le_gt_dec x b) then ... else ... ) else ...
```

But by defining functions with this technique it gets very complicated later on when I need to prove stuff on these functions because it makes many cases, so I was wondering if anyone had a better way to define such functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably searching for this:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Definition IsIn (a:nat) (b:nat) (x:nat) : bool :=
  andb (leb a x) (leb x b).
```

Comment: actually I didn't want to return the boolean corresponding to x being in the interval [a,b] but being able to test for it in a if ... then ... else condition in a function.

Comment: You can just use it in an if statement: `if andb (leb a x) (leb x b) then 1 else 2` or if you want to abstract it in `IsIn`, call it: `if IsIn 2 5 4 then 1 else 2`.

Comment: @user3260646: Once IsIn returns that boolean, you can test for it directly in your if.

Comment: Yep it works with the IsIn in the if, (you have to `Require Import Coq.Arith.Compare_dec`)

Comment: Yes, though `Coq.Arith.Arith` reexports `Coq.Arith.Compare_dec`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on @thoferon's answer: Coq let's you add your own syntactic sugar, so you can write

```
Notation "A && B" := (andb A B). 
Notation "A || B" := (orb  A B).
```

And then

```
Eval compute in (if true && false then 1 else 0).
    = 0 : nat
Eval compute in (if true || false then 1 else 0).
    = 1 : nat
```